# Determining a limit

Tags: calculus

I'm having troubles showing that
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x^2+2x}}{x} = -1.
$$
In particular, why is the following derivation wrong?
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x^2+2x}}{x} = \lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty} \frac{x\sqrt{1+2/x}}{x} =  \lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty} \sqrt{1+2/x} = \sqrt{1+\lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty}(2/x)} = 1.$$

Comment: $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|=-x$ if $x<0$.

Comment: Thanks! I totally missed that. :)

Comment: What you could have done to discover your mistake was to plug in some number like $x=-100000$.

Comment: I have trouble with negative numbers. Maybe not for this problem, but for more complicated ones, I would probably let $u=-x$, find the limit of $\dfrac{\sqrt{u^2-2u}}{-u}$ as $u\to\infty$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: I like that approach.

Comment: @somebody : +1 for showing your work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake is here
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x^2+2x}}{x} = \lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty} \frac{x\sqrt{1+2/x}}{x} = \ldots = 1.
$$

The correct is 
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x^2+2x}}{x} = \lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty} \frac{-x\sqrt{1+2/x}}{x} = \ldots = -1
$$
since $x<0$ ($\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$, for example $\sqrt{(-1254)^2}=1254$).